# .then() function never running for call to blockchain

Tags: javascript, promise, blockchain, ethereum, web3js

Please find below my code snippet. Here credentialHash is not being set in the .then() call. Neither the "In then" or "Callback rejected" are being printed so I know that it is not running but I cant understand why. I've also included code for the setHash function in my smart contract.

```js
let hash;
    await ipfs.add(JSON.stringify(this.state.credential)).then((result, error) => {
      hash = result.path;
      if (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return;
      }
      // Store hash on blockchain
      console.log("Hash before BC:" + hash);
      this.state.contract.methods.setHash(hash).send({from: this.state.account}).then((resolve) => {
    console.log("In then")
    this.setState({credentialHash: hash});
  }, (rejected) => {
    console.log("Callback rejected");
  });
      console.log("After setting:" + this.state.credentialHash);
    });
```

`function setHash(string memory _CredentialHash) public returns(string memory) { credentialHash = _CredentialHash; return _CredentialHash; }`

The result returned from `console.log(this.state.contract.methods.setHash(hash).send({from: this.state.account}))` is :

```
Proxy {promise: Promise, eventEmitter: EventEmitter, resolve: ƒ, reject: ƒ}
[[Handler]]: Object
get: ƒ proxyHandler(target, name)
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Target]]: PromiEvent
eventEmitter: EventEmitter
_events: Events
[[Prototype]]: Object
_eventsCount: 0
[[Prototype]]: Object
promise: Promise
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "pending"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined
reject: ƒ ()
resolve: ƒ ()
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

Comment: If you know that the "fulfilled" callback is not executed then check the "rejected" callback -> [`.then(onFulfilled[, onRejected])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: Why do you `await` a Promise if you add it a `.then()`? Or rather, why dou you add a `.then()` to a Promise if you already `await` it? You are mixing two syntax styles

Comment: @JeremyThille that would be ok to mix them as long as the .then returns a promise... which does not look to be the case

Comment: @JeremyThille I have removed the await before ipfs.add(...) and the problem remains. I am pretty new to js.

Comment: @Andreas I tried testing the rejected callback using the updated code, the log did not print in either case.

Comment: @mmonteirocl `.then()` [_always_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#return_value) returns a `Promise`

Comment: It looks like the method expects a hash and you're sending it a file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default number of transactionConfirmationBlocks is 24 which takes a long time to complete. Setting this to 1 as below solved my issue.

```
this.setState({contract: new web3.eth.Contract(
      credentialArtifact.abi,
      deployedNetworkCred.address,
        {transactionConfirmationBlocks: 1}
  )});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try dropping the `.then()` syntax entirely and use only the `async/await` style. What does the code below give?

```
let hash, result;

try {
  result = await ipfs.add(JSON.stringify(this.state.credential))
  hash = result.path;
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error)
  return;
}

// Store hash on blockchain
console.log("Hash before BC:" + hash);

try {
  await this.state.contract.methods.setHash(hash).send({
    from: this.state.account
  })
} catch(error) {
  console.log("Callback rejected");
  return
}

this.setState({
  credentialHash: hash
});

console.log("After setting:" + this.state.credentialHash);
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. This only prints the "Hash before BC: xyz" as it is getting stuck on `await this.state.contract.methods.setHash(hash).send({ from: this.state.account })`

Comment: So it's loading forever without resolving. No idea what this function does, though

Comment: The setHash functon is included in the OP and essentially sets the credentialHash value for a smart contract and returns

Comment: Yeah but I mean what does it _do_ in practice; not what's its goal, what the code in it is actually doing (HTTP call most likely). Because this function seems of be hanging forever, that's the source of your trouble

Comment: The call is calling my method on for my smart contract on the blockchain running locally using Ganache. The get call works fine for the same contract so I'm very unsure what the issue is. I've added the result returned from the call if I log it in the OP :)